# Unix- IF condition issue

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement

I'm having a problem in if condition usage under Unix. Need your help in sorting it out.

```
if (a=1 and b is not null) or a=0 and b is null
echo "sucess"
else 
echo failure
```

I tried the below code but I am getting an error.

```
if [[ ${a} -eq 1 ] && [[ ! -z ${b} ]]] || [[ ${a} -eq 0 ] && [[ -z ${b} ]]]; then
    echo "sucess"
else 
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Please *never* state you "got an error" **without** telling what the exact error message is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your your test:

1. The double bracket, [[, is a bash keyword. Bash will interpret [[ as a call to its internal test command, and not as the two layers of nesting brackets you're intending.
2. AND (&&) and OR (||) tests fail within single brackets.

There's two ways to fix your test:

Put your AND and OR tests within parenthesis, '()':

```
if ( [ $a -eq 1 ] && [ ! -z $b ] ) || ( [ $a -eq 0 ] && [ -z $b ] ) ; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

Or, using the bash extended test, put your AND and OR test inside a double bracket set '[[ ]]' and omit the internal single bracket test:

```
if [[  $a -eq 1  &&  ! -z $b   ]] || [[  $a -eq 0  &&  -z $b  ]] ; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

Note that *-a* and *-o* tests are deprecated, so sticking to && and || is better in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your code like spaces between `[` and `]` signs, like this:

```
if [ [ ${a} -eq 1 ] -a [ [ ! -z ${b} ] ] ] -o [ [ ${a} -eq 0 ] -a [ [ -z ${b} ] ] ]; then echo "sucess"; else echo "Failure"; fi
```

where `-a` means "and" and `-o` means "or"

sometimes you use to much `[` and `]`; furthermore, `! -z` can be replaced by `-n`. It could be fixed like this:

```
if [ \( $a -eq 1 \) -a \( -n "$b" \) ] || [ \( $a -eq 0 \) -a \( -z "$b" \) ]; then
 echo "sucess"
else
 echo "Failure"
fi
```

is it clearer?

Comment: Why not? Try to run my example

Comment: `if [ ( $a -eq 1 ) -a ( -n "$b" ) ] || [ ( $a -eq 0 ) -a ( -z "$b" ) ]; then echo "sucess"; else echo "Failure"; fi` -> ``bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$a'``

Comment: What you needed is an escaped version. This is one of the reasons why use of single brackets is not commendable in Bash: `if [ \( $a -eq 1 \) -a \( -n "$b" \) ] || [ \( $a -eq 0 \) -a \( -z "$b" \) ]; then echo "sucess"; else echo "Failure"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

> if (a=1 and b is not null) or a=0 and b is null echo "sucess" else
>   echo failure

```
if [[ $a == 1 && -n $b ]] || [[ $a == 0 && -z $b ]]; then
    echo success
else
    echo failure
fi
```

Or

```
[[ $a == 1 && -n $b ]] || [[ $a == 0 && -z $b ]] && echo success || echo failure
```

Other forms:

```
[[ ($a == 1 && -n $b) || ($a == 0 && -z $b) ]]
[[ (a -eq 1 && -n $b) || (a -eq 0 && -z $b) ]]
```

And it's just one of the situations where using `(( ))` to do numerical comparisons is out of the question. Something those who promote `(( ))` as an imperative operator for such should consider.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more a comment than an answer, but please remember `bash` is not a general data processing tool. That is some constructs does not translate very well from C-like to shell -- like the "complex" logical expression in this particular example. For ease of understanding and/or writing, you should try to rely on shell specific features.

All this globish verbiage to said that, assuming your variables hold "integer" or "nothing", your test might be simply rewritten as:

```
case "${a}:${b}" in
    0: | 1:?*)
          echo "Success"
          ;;
    *)    echo "Failure"
esac
```